# Sending Data extremely slow or RDS

Tags: networking, mysql, amazon-web-services, linux-networking, amazon-rds

I have the following two profiles for a basic `SELECT` STATEMENT:

```
select count(*) from mturk_completion;
```

Here are the two profiles:

```
# My Local machine, using a local db
Status                Duration
starting              0.000045
checking permissions  0.000006
Opening tables        0.000015
init                  0.000011
System lock           0.000006
optimizing            0.000004
statistics            0.000011
preparing             0.000009
executing             0.000002
Sending data          0.034015 ########
end                   0.000012
query end             0.000006
closing tables        0.000011
freeing items         0.000036
cleaning up           0.000010
```

And then here it is on my AWS ec2 large instance using an RDS mysql db:

```
starting                0.000068
checking permissions    0.000016
Opening tables          0.000028
init                    0.000024
System lock             0.000018
optimizing              0.000015
statistics              0.000022
preparing               0.000022
executing               0.000012
Sending data            0.446171 #########
end                     0.000036
query end               0.000018
closing tables          0.000023
freeing items           0.00009
cleaning up             0.000013
```

Most of the numbers are comparable except the Sending data part is more than ten times slower on the RDS instance!! What could account for that, and how would I fix this?

Here is the RDS instance information:

[image]

Comment: Is the same amount of data in both instances?

Comment: Yes, the count is `202809` in both. Same databases for both.

Comment: I guess a performance issue if its not a dedicated server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sending data
>
> The thread is reading and processing rows for a SELECT statement, and
>   sending data to the client. Because operations occurring during this
>   **this state tend to perform large amounts of disk access (reads)**, it is
>   often the longest-running state over the lifetime of a given query.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/general-thread-states.html

I suspect disk access speed is the difference.

In your first test it seems you have a local machine connecting to a local DB server with a local hard disk. In your second test you're connecting to a remote DB server with a remote hard disk (ie. EBS).

EBS (which is what RDS uses for storage) is [significantly slower](http://victortrac.com/ec2-ephemeral-disks-vs-ebs-volumes-in-raid.html) than instance storage, which I imagine might still be slower than an unloaded local disk on your workstation (especially if you have an SSD).

However in exchange for the performance loss you gain a number of benefits enabled by the abstracted nature of ELB:

- The ability to take snapshots of your instance and launch new instances from your snapshot
- The ability to resize your disk
- The ability to change the performance of your disk (via provisioned IOPS)
- The ability for your RDS instance to be transparently moved to a new host which might occur during a reboot or instance type change

Which is why most people accept the performance penalty.

If the performance loss is significant then you can try a few things:

- [provisioned IOPS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/details/)
- Run your own MySQL instance on EC2 using instance storage. I don't recommend this though as it would be very difficult to avoid data-loss if your instance gets stopped, and you won't be able to resize your disk if your data grows.
- Run your own MySQL instance on EC2 using EBS in RAID
- Scale horizontally, add read replicas if the IO on your master is becoming a bottleneck
- Implement data caching within your application

Comment: Thanks, increasing the IOPS seemed to resolve this issue, in that my production db now matches the relative speed of my local db.